# C# WPF touch keyboard input on textbox shows memory error

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, on-screen-keyboard

I have a wpf application running on a Windows 7 Embedded client.
The touch keyboard is correctly shown when a textbox is focused. But if I press a touch, I have this message :

[memory error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seMLv.png)

I'm able to use the software until I click on close, which exit the process. 
I didn't find any helping issue for now. 
Visual Studio doesn't say me anything special on my development machine.

Comment: same error occurs if you run it on a device/simulator/other machine?

Comment: Yes on different desktop including one with touch screen (but Windows 8.1), the program didn't crash.

Comment: so no crash if used on a different system? Sounds like its an issue with your dev machine